# Why is SQL not considered a programming language?

Tags: terminology, database-theory

If a database is just a computer system that implements a database management system, and we use SQL to tell it what to do, why don't we consider SQL to be a programming langauge?

From Wikipedia:

> A programming language is any set of rules that converts strings, or
> graphical program elements in the case of visual programming language,
> to various kinds of machine code output.

With SQL, you run your code on a RDMS, which inputs data, manipulates it, and outputs it when you run queries. Why do people not consider it to be a programming language then?

Comment: Because it would have been called "SPL" ?

Comment: This is mostly opinion-based and comes from a presupposition: for example I consider it to be a programming language, and if I didn't, it might not be the same reason that others have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose it is a matter of definition(s) and whom you may ask. Some start would be whether the language is [Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness). SQL92 is not, but extended with recursive CTE and Window functions you can build a [Cyclic Tag System](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicTagSystem.html) that can emulate a turing machine. There are also procedural extensions such as T-SQL, PL-SQL and whatnot that would formally turn it into a programming language (if turing completeness is sufficient).

However, I get a feeling that what we mean by being a programming language is also how easy it is to solve a general-purpose problem. [Game of life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) is Turing complete, but few of us would consider it to be a programming language. [Brainfuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) on the other hand is by most of us considered a programming language but is hardly useful other than for recreational purposes.

Perhaps it is the intended use of the language that defines whether it is considered as a programming language? SQL is mainly intended as a data transformation language and as such, perhaps not considered as a general programming language. Do we consider Excel Formulas to be a programming language or not, given that [Excel lambda is turing complete](https://www.infoq.com/articles/excel-lambda-turing-complete/)?

Not much of an answer to your question, but some thoughts

Comment: https://xkcd.com/2556/